# Unable to fetch field value of a firestore document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore for this project where i want to fetch a field value of data type String from a document and search a document that matches the String value in another collection. I made 4 activity in Android Studio that does the same but with different documents and collections. I made a document reference of a document to fetch a value of the field "HOD" and it will get stored in a String variable by the function "getString()". Though it works for 3 of those activities but it does not work with the last activity. It just unable to get the desired data. Please help me solve this problem.

Code of the file that is not working -

```
package com.polytechnic.thectsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

public class Faculty_ME extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    private int i = 2;
    private int name_id, designation_id, education_id, email_id, mobile_id, email_label_id, mobile_label_id, hod_id;

    String HOD = "";
    String Head = "";
    String field = "HOD";

    DocumentReference docRef;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_faculty__me);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        firebaseFirestore.document("Departments/Mechanical Engineering")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot doc1 = task.getResult();
                            Head = doc1.getString("HOD");           // problem occurs here unable to get the value
                            HOD = "Departments/Mechanical Engineering/Teachers/".concat(Head); // error occurs here unable to concat Null (Null Pointer Exception)
                            docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(HOD);
                            docRef.get()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                                                name_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_name_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                designation_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_designation_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                education_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_education_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                email_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_email_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                mobile_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_mobile_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                email_label_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_email_label_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                mobile_label_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_mobile_label_1", "id", getPackageName());
                                                hod_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_hod", "id", getPackageName());

                                                textView = findViewById(name_id);
                                                textView.setText(Head);
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(designation_id);
                                                textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Designation"));
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(email_label_id);
                                                textView.setText("Email");
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(email_id);
                                                textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Email"));
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(mobile_label_id);
                                                textView.setText("Mobile");
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(mobile_id);
                                                textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Mobile"));
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(education_id);
                                                textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Education"));
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                textView = findViewById(hod_id);
                                                textView.setText("Head of the department");
                                                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Departments").document("Mechanical Engineering").collection("Teachers")
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                i = 2;
                                                for (final QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {

                                                    if (documentSnapshot.getId() == null || documentSnapshot.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                                                    } else if (documentSnapshot.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(Head) || documentSnapshot.getId().equals(Head)) {
                                                    } else {

                                                        name_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_name_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                                                        designation_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_designation_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                                                        education_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_education_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                                                        email_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_email_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                                                        mobile_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_mobile_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                                                        email_label_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_email_label_" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                                                        mobile_label_id = getResources().getIdentifier("me_mobile_label_" + i, "id", getPackageName());

                                                        textView = findViewById(name_id);
                                                        textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getId());
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        textView = findViewById(designation_id);
                                                        textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Designation"));
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        textView = findViewById(email_label_id);
                                                        textView.setText("Email");
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        textView = findViewById(email_id);
                                                        textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Email"));
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        textView = findViewById(mobile_label_id);
                                                        textView.setText("Mobile");
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        textView = findViewById(mobile_id);
                                                        textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Mobile"));
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        textView = findViewById(education_id);
                                                        textView.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Education"));
                                                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                                        i = i + 1;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

"Head" variable should get initialized with value of the filed "HOD" but it returns null and Null Pointer Exception occurs at concat().

Error Msg - `NullPointerException: string args == null`

Comment: Please add your database structure a screenshot. Please also indicate at which line of code are you getting that error.

Comment: Kindly show complete error log and the database structure